# How to set another odbc driver on my Advanced installer?

Tags: installation, odbc, driver, advanced-installer

I want to set from my advanced installer project to use another ODBC Driver - for exemple Odbc Driver 17 for SQL Server, not the default one, SQL Server. I found information about how to set another odbc driver - https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/driver-properties.html, but there is specified something about adding a dll file, and I can't find a dll file for odbc driver. I tried to add a .msi there, but it's not working. The reason is, there are some security settings on the client, and the patch cannot be aplied when is set the default one.
I added the driver to the prerequisites for the upgrade version, and set the odbc driver in the SQL Databases- Predefined connection, but the installer seems to work, but, when I tried to run the application, is not working (before that everything working), the database is created, but empty, whithout tables, the login missing.

Any information about this, can be really helpfull.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest approach to deploy ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server is to add its MSI setup package as a pre-install prerequisite in your Advanced Installer setup project (in Prerequisites section of the project).

Just download the [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server MSI setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and include it as a pre-install prerequisite in your Advanced Installer setup project.